# perl regular expression new lines

Tags: regex, perl

Code comes like

```
    <dt> Some
                     text</dt>
    <dd>some value</dd>
```

I would like to be able to **remove only the new lines not finishing with an html tag**.
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify the expected output / show us some real input?  Parsing HTML is rather involved, but matching a > followed by a newline is easy.

Comment: In 50% of the cases `$in =~ s/ ([^>]) \s*?\n\s* /$1/xg;` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in command-line Perl like this

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!>)\n//' my.html
```

or this

```
perl -pe 's/([^>])\n/$1/' my.html
```